# Request count sum for last 1 hour

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I have a use case where I want to set the alerts from grafana on hourly basis. In this hourly alert I want to get the request count for each API in last 1 hour and collect them and sent along with the alert. I tried different combination of using

1. sum - `sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1h]))`
2. increase - `increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1h])`
3. sum_over_time - `sum_over_time(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1h])`
4. count_over_time - `count_over_time(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1h])`

While I am validating the result from request count it is not adding up. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am search for the very same thing. Did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: @tcurdt I have referred this [article](https://community.grafana.com/t/time-interval-grouping-and-data-scaling/154) on time grouping while it does not answer to my exact query but it adds some reference. Hope this helps.